# How to get VBA to run through the click of a link or once clicked in Outlook email when someone else recieves the email?

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink, outlook, automation

I am trying to write a macro in VBA (Outlook or Excel) so that when I send an email to someone else I can include my macro to automatically run once the email is clicked, or 5 seconds after it is clicked. If this is too complicated or confusing just ask I know my explaining and probably understanding of what I am doing is poor.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide anything for that. I.e. it is not possible to implement the required task in VBA.

Comment: Are there any workarounds to get this done? i.e. save it as a text file that opens and runs once email is clicked or am I just not at all possible?

Comment: No, you need to install the add-in on the remote machine if you want any code to run.

Comment: Yeah, the add-in is installed on their machine, we work together

Comment: In that case you can handle the [ItemChange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865866(v=office.15).aspx) event of the Items class. Also you may find the [PropertyChange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869749(v=office.15).aspx) event helpful.

Comment: I am not trying to look for appointments which is what ItemChange is for? Not sure how propertychange helps? What is the idea behind using these two to have the macro run on his computer once he opens it or clicks the link in it or however?

Comment: The UnRead property value will be changed when the user clicks on the email. The Outlook object model doesn't provide any events for links.